# Updating Azure iOS SDK to 1.2.2

Tags: ios, xcode, azure

I am trying to update Azure SDK for iOS from 1.1.5 to 1.2.2 and can't compile the app any more.

```
duplicate symbol _storageVersion in:
    /azuresdk-iOS-v1.2.2/WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework/WindowsAzureMobileServices(MSLocalStorage.o)
    /azuresdk-iOS-v1.2.2/WindowsAzureMessaging.framework/WindowsAzureMessaging(SBLocalStorage.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anybody here use 1.2.2 ? Or I should just switch back to 1.1.5 :(

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a bug when using both messaging and mobile services SDK together (starting with 1.2.2 of MS)  While we look into getting a fix, you can drop down to 1.1.5 or look at replacing the use of the messaging framework with the new client.push methods shown here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-ios-get-started-push/

(note: the second option does require you to use enhanced push (notification hubs) option within your mobile service)

We'll work on getting an updated 1.2.3 release out that address this particular issue.

Comment: Version 1.2.3 is now live, and this issue should now be resolved.